# Trying to create a link to an HTML file in Webstorms

Tags: javascript, html, file, hyperlink

I'm currently doing an assignment that involves modifying a game called Perlenspiel using an IDE (in my case, I'm using Webstorms.) I managed to mod the game properly as my changes are reflected into the actual game when I open it on Google Chrome (my browser.) But the assignment also requires me to copy the entire directory (I guess it means "folder containing the relevant files"), which includes the .js file and .html file that allow me to modify and launch the game respectively, to the cloud (Dropbox, Google Docs.) But the hard part is to create a link to the .html file in the directory where my .js file is also located. How do you do that? The game doesn't seem to work when I merely try to open the .html file after uploading it on Dropbox alongside the other relevant files such as the .js file. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You're linking *from* the JS file *to* the HTML file? Usually it's the other way. Show some code, please.

Comment: No, I'm trying to create a link to the HTML file that's in the same directory as the .js file.

You want the code to the .html file or the .js file?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a link to a file on a server? All that other information is irrelevant and misleading, in that case. What's wrong with http://example.com/mydirectory/myfile.html?